# update wiki message from text file

Tags: mediawiki

Is it possible to have my wiki load a line of text from a *.txt file and display it somewhere on the Main Page?  Something like a "daily message" that comes straight from the txt file and  does not involve editing the wiki manually?

My wiki is running on Ubuntu Mate and is as follows:

[image]

**UPDATE**: Based on Alexander's answer I have this working fine, but caching is not behaving as expected.  I want the external data to show up immediately upon clicking browser refresh button (so I have set cache times to zero) - but this does not work.  The only way I have found to force the external text to be refreshed is to A) edit the wiki page (which forces a reload), or B) stop/start the apache server.

In my `LocalSettings.php` file I have:

```
wfLoadExtension( 'ExternalData' );
$edgCacheExpireTime=0;
$edgFilePath['inject'] = '/home/rw/my_external_data.txt';
```

In my main page wiki i have:

```
{{#get_file_data:
  file=inject
  |format=text
  |data=inject=text
  |cache seconds=0
 }}{{#external_value:inject}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install ''[External Data](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:External_Data)'', then:

**Old style:**

define in your `LocalSettings.php`

```php
wfLoadExtension( 'ExternalData' );
$edgFilePath['inject'] = '/path/to/your/file.txt';
$edgCacheExpireTime = 10; // only ten seconds.
```

and add to your Main page:

```
{{#get_file_data: file = inject
  | format = text
  | data = inject=__text
  | cache seconds = 10
 }}{{#external_value:inject}}
```

**New style:**

define in your `LocalSettings.php`

```php
wfLoadExtension( 'ExternalData' );
$wgExternalDataSources['inject'] = [
    'path' => '/path/to/your/file.txt',
    'min cache seconds' => 10
];
```

and add to your Main page:

```
{{#get_external_data: file = inject
  | format = text
  | data = inject=__text
  | cache seconds = 10
 }}{{#external_value:inject}}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander.  I don't know how to run `composer update` in the ExternalData directory.  There is a `composer.json` file in that directory but I don't know how to run `composer update` as specified [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:External_Data#Installation).

Comment: Provided you have composer installed, simply type `composer update` or `php composer.phar update` in the terninal while in `extensions/ExternalData`.

Comment: I don’t know what composer is.

Comment: Ok, nice!  Thank you Alexander.  Works like a charm.  When i run `composer update` it says there is a version 2.0 available (the version I have after `apt-get install composer` is 1.10.10).  I am leaving it at version 1.10.10 since the composer wiki page you link above says, "Currently, only Composer 1.x is supported by MediaWiki. "

Comment: I added an update to my post concerning how to set the cache delay so changes to the external data text file show up immediately (with browser refresh). I  can't make that happen.

Comment: I updated my answer to set caching time to ten seconds. Browser refresh may not be enough anyway, you may need `?action=purge`.

Comment: Hi @alexandermashin I made the changes to `cache seconds` and to `$edgCacheExpireTime` and neither appear to have any affect. I added the following at bottom of page to do a purge but purging does nothing either: `{{fullurl:MediaWiki:mainpage|action=purge}}`. The only thing that actually refreshes is to edit the page or stop/start mysql and apache2 services.

Comment: By "purge" I meant that you click on http://your.wiki/Your_page?action=purge link on your page in the browser to invalidate parser cache and web server cache.

Comment: Thank you.  I found `purge` under special pages and then put in `Main_Page`  and the purge worked as you said.  Not sure why the `cache seconds` and `edgCacheExpireTime` don't do it, maybe something weird in my setup.  Anyway, thanks again sir!

Comment: Looked promising, but I get `Error: no local variable "inject" has been set.`, even though it is all exactly as described here for LocalSettings.php and in the page.

Comment: See the corrected answer: `text` → `__text`.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin: Unfortunately, still the same error. In case it matters, using ED v. 3.1 in Mediawiki 1.31.10 on Debian 10 with Apache, PostgreSQL, and PHP version 7.4.3.

Comment: Did you use double underscore? Are there any other error messages?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin: Yes: `{{#get_external_data: file=inject|format=text|data=inject=__text}}{{#external_value:inject}}`. Full error is "Unable to get the contents of file /docs/www-wiki/popular_pages.txt. Error: no local variable "inject" has been set.". (My PHP version is actually 7.3.19)

Comment: The error `Unable to get the contents of file…` is issued when a file exists but cannot be read -- a rare situation, possibly caused by wrong file permissions. What is strange is that the message contains a real filename, while it should contain the alias `inject`.

Comment: Do you really have
`$wgExternalDataSources['inject'] = [
    'path' = '/docs/www-wiki/popular_pages.txt',
    'min cache seconds' => 10
];`
in your `LocalSettings.php`?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin: It works! After replacing `'path'=...` with `'path'=>...`. I also edited it in your answer. Before, it was giving "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ']'" in the Apache logs. Took me a while to find it... All good now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you. It was stupid of me to confuse `=` and `=>`.